# Ruby on rails with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have very little experience with rails and I am trying to use jQuery datepicker in my rails application.

My application has multiple subtasks,which have modal associated with them,I have datepicker field on these modal's.

What I want is when i select a date,an ajax call should be made to my controller and it should save selected date in my database.
Then on save i refresh my page through ajax.

Here are the codes

Footer here is the modal footer,i have just created a different partial for it so that i can refresh it after a date gets saved,so that the selected date gets reflected here.

/*_footer.html.erb*/

```
<div class="row" id="footer_<%=subtask.id%>">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-bottom:-20px;float:left;">
        <a class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn btn-success">Start Date
        </a>
        <%= form_tag({:controller => 'subtasks', :action => 'updateDatestart'},:remote=>'true') do %>
        <%= text_field_tag "text", :start_date, :class => "dateFilter form-control datepickerstart_#{subtask.id}"%>
        <%end%>
        <!--input class="form-control" id="datepickerstart_<%=subtask.id%>" type="text" placeholder="StartDate"-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-bottom:-20px;float:right;">
        <a class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn btn-danger">End Date
        </a>
        <input class="form-control" id="datepickerend_<%=subtask.id%>" type="text" placeholder="EndDate">
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.dateFilter').datepicker({
            onSelect:function(){
                updateTable("start");
            }
        });
    });

    function updateTable(value)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/subtasks/updateDate"+value,


data: { subtasks: { id:<%=subtask.id%>,start_date:$('.dateFilter').datepicker().val()}},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $(".datepickerstart_<%=subtask.id%>").datepicker('setDate',$(".datepickerstart_<%=subtask.id%>").val());

             } 
        });
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

/*subtask controller*/

```
def updateDatestart
        @subtask=Subtask.find(params[:subtasks][:id])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @subtask.update_attribute(:start_date,params[:subtasks][:start_date])
            format.js
            end
        end
    end
```

/*updateDatestart.js.erb*/

```
$('#footer_'+ <%=@subtask.id %>).html('<%=j(render partial: "subtasks/footer",locals: {subtask: @subtask})%>');
```

The question here is that on selecting a date through datepicker,the correct date gets sent.Till here everything is fine,but my datepicker input box,still shows "start date" as its value instead of the selected date.

Also another issue is that,once i have selected a date for a subtask,now whenever i click on it,it should fetch that date from the database and show me,instead of again showing "start date" as the value.

Please help me,i am stuck on this from a very long time.

Alright,i have found a solution to this,posting it here so that if other's have the same issue their precious time would be saved

```
/*Solution that worked for me*/
```

Here is my solution

```
1.First i removed the different action which i made for updatedatestart and updatedateend.Instead now i am using the same update method provided by ruby for both of them.

/*subtask_controller.rb*/

def update

        @subtask=Subtask.find(params[:id])
        #@task=@subtask.task
        #@subtask.description=params[:subtask][:description]
        respond_to do |format|
            #if @subtask.update_attribute(:description,params[:subtask][:description])
            if @subtask.update_attributes(params[:subtask])
                format.html{redirect_to @project}
                format.js
            else
                render new
            end
        end
```

My _footer.html.erb file

```
<div class="row" id="footer_<%=subtask.id%>">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-bottom:-20px;float:left;">
        <a class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn btn-success" style="border-bottom-left-radius:0px;border-bottom-right-radius:0px;">Start Date
        </a>
        <%=form_for subtask,:remote=>:true,:method => :put do |f| %>
        <%=f.hidden_field :name%>
        <%= f.hidden_field :description,rows:'5',cols:'12',:class=>'myarea'%>
        <%=f.hidden_field :task_id%>
        <%=f.text_field :start_date,:class => "datepicker_#{subtask.id} form-control",:id=>"datepickerstart_#{subtask.id}",:style=> "border-top-left-radius:0px;border-top-right-radius:0px;"%>
        <%=f.hidden_field :end_date%>
        <%end%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-bottom:-20px;float:right;">
        <a class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn btn-danger"style="border-bottom-left-radius:0px;border-bottom-right-radius:0px;">End Date
        </a>
        <%=form_for subtask,:remote=>:true,:method => :put do |f| %>
        <%=f.hidden_field :name%>
        <%= f.hidden_field :description,rows:'5',cols:'12',:class=>'myarea'%>
        <%=f.hidden_field :task_id%>
        <%=f.text_field :end_date,:class => "datepicker_#{subtask.id} form-control",:id=>"datepickerend_#{subtask.id}",:style=> "border-top-left-radius:0px;border-top-right-radius:0px;"%>
        <%=f.hidden_field :start_date%>
        <%end%>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.datepicker_<%=subtask.id%>').datepicker({
            onClose: function(strDate, datepicker) {
                if(strDate == "") {
                return;
                }
                $(this).parent().trigger('submit.rails')
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
</div>
```

That's it,this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) (you can probably eliminate the controller parameter) instead of `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_for(subtask, {:action => 'updateDatestart'},:remote=>'true') do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :start_date, :class => "dateFilter form-control datepickerstart_#{subtask.id}"
<% end %>
```

The `form_for` helper will read the attributes of your record. You'll also use a variable for the block, `f`, and use the `text_field` helper instead of `text_field_tag`.